# Is it safe to assign default values to class members in Java?

Tags: java

Here's are two classes, Passenger and Car. Instead of initializing all private members of the Car class in all constructors, I thought of setting default values for them and overwriting specific members' values if provided by the instance creator.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Passenger {
    private String name;

    Passenger(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Car {
    private String color = "red";
    private int numberOfWheels = 4;
    private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();

    Car() {}

    Car(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    Car(int numberOfWheels) {
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
    }

    public void addPassenger(Passenger p) {
        this.passengers.add(p);
    }
}
```

Is it safe to set default values to class members like this? Any pitfalls to avoid for any particular data types (even other than the ones I have used)?

Comment: Is there a setter for `color`? No? Then it should be `final` - in that case your pattern won't work. Honestly I don't see any benefit to it anyway - it just adds noise and room for error.

Comment: if this is data to be stored on a database, it might be better to set default values there....

Comment: One obvious problem is that you can't make the fields `final`. That's fine if you want them to be mutable. Otherwise, consider passing the default via a standard constructor: `Car() { this("red", 4); }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe. 
Personally I prefer initialize where is declaration if is a common value for all constructors. If I have more constructor is not very pleasure to write that thing multiple times. And for me is more clear what value have.

Comment: Then chain your constructors. I don't buy the argument at all. The cost of not being able to declare things `final` is just too high.